# How to get the unique values of a variable in new columns in a R Data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

## Sample Data

```
mydf <- data.frame(Vehicle.ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), Frame.ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
           Lane = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), lane.change = c(".", ".", "yes", ".", ".","yes",".","."),
           Preceding.Vehicle.ID = c(10,10,5,5,5,6,6,6),
           Following.Vehicle.ID = c(20,20,50,50,50,30,30,30))
```

## Data Description

**Vehicle.ID**: ID of a vehicle
**Frame.ID**: Frame number (1 frame = 0.1 seconds)
**Lane**: Number of the currently occupied lane
**lane.change**: "." means vehicle did not change the lane in this frame and "yes" means vehicle change the lane in this frame
**Preceding.Vehicle.ID** and **Following.Vehicle.ID**: IDs of the vehicle on front and vehicle behind in the current lane, in the given frame.

## What I want to do:

I want to find:
1. All the lanes occupied by the vehicle. The current lane is given in the "Lane" column. All the other lanes which the vehicle moved to are the target lanes. I want to create new columns containing the lane numbers of all target lanes i.e. **target.lane1**, **target.lane2**, etc.
2. Similarly, I want to put all the preceding vehicle IDs and following vehicle IDs in new columns i.e. preceding vehicle in target lane 1 & 2: PVtl1, PVtl2, and following vehicle in target lane 1 & 2: FVtl1, FVtl2.

## Final desired form of data frame:

```
mydf.final <- mydf %>%
  mutate(target.lane1 = 2, PVtl1 = 5, FVtl1 = 50, 
         target.lane2 = 3, PVtl2 = 6, FVtl2 = 30)
```

## What I have tried:

Honestly, I can't figure out how to do this. I tried using:

```
> mydf <- mydf %>%
+   mutate(pvtl1 = data.frame(unique(Preceding.Vehicle.ID)))
Error: not compatible with STRSXP
```

but get the error as you see.

Please guide me. I want to use `dplyr` for this.

### EDIT:

I have tried using `for loop` and it worked for this sample data:

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(mydf$Lane))){
  mydf[,paste("target.lane",i, sep=".")] =  unique(mydf$Lane)[i]
  mydf[,paste("PVtl",i, sep=".")] =  unique(mydf$Preceding.Vehicle.ID)[i]
  mydf[,paste("FVtl",i, sep=".")] =  unique(mydf$Following.Vehicle.ID)[i]
}
```

Here, the target.lane.1, PVtl1 and FVtl1 are useless because they just include the info for first current lane which is not the target lane so I can remove them later.
But original data is big and there are many more unique Vehicle.IDs. Using the `for loop` doesn't seem to be a wise idea. How can I achieve the same faster using `dplyr`?

### EDIT 2 (dplyr solution that works for me)

Looks like no one is in helping mood today. I figured out a `dplyr` solution which can be applied if there are about 8 lane changes:

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(ul = n_distinct(Lane),
         target.lane.1 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-2)],
         PVtl1 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.1, Lane)],
         FVtl1 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.1, Lane)],
         target.lane.2 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-3)],
         PVtl2 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.2, Lane)],
         FVtl2 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.2, Lane)],
         target.lane.3 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-4)],
         PVtl3 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.3, Lane)],
         FVtl3 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.3, Lane)],
         target.lane.4 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-5)],
         PVtl4 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.4, Lane)],
         FVtl4 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.4, Lane)],
         target.lane.5 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-6)],
         PVtl5 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.5, Lane)],
         FVtl5 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.5, Lane)],
         target.lane.6 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-7)],
         PVtl6 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.6, Lane)],
         FVtl6 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.6, Lane)],
         target.lane.7 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-8)],
         PVtl7 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.7, Lane)],
         FVtl7 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.7, Lane)],
         target.lane.8 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-9)],
         PVtl8 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.8, Lane)],
         FVtl8 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.8, Lane)],
         target.lane.9 = unique(Lane)[ul - (ul-10)],
         PVtl9 = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.9, Lane)],
         FVtl9 = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.9, Lane)],
         target.lane.final = unique(Lane)[ul],
         PVtlf = Preceding.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.final, Lane)],
         FVtlf = Following.Vehicle.ID[match(target.lane.final, Lane)])
```

Still, I want to modify my code so that the new columns are created based on the number of observed lane changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by creating a dataset with the new columns of interest and then joining the new dataset back to the original dataset using `left_join`.  I added the information for number of observed lane changes to the dataset so the number of new columns can be based on the number of observed lane changes.  The bulk of the work is in the reshaping of the dataset using functions from `tidyr` to create the new column headers (using `gather` and `unite`) and then making the new columns (`spread`).  I didn't put the new columns in the desired order, but you can certainly do that.

The code below should work if you have multiple `Vehicle.ID` values.  If you only have one `Vehicle.ID` you don't need to `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
    filter(lane.change == "yes") %>%
    group_by(Vehicle.ID) %>%
    mutate(order = 1:n()) %>%
    select(-Frame.ID, -lane.change) %>%
    rename(target.lane = Lane,  Pvtl = Preceding.Vehicle.ID, FVtl = Following.Vehicle.ID) %>%
    gather(group, number, target.lane, Pvtl, FVtl) %>%
    unite(group1, group, order, sep = "") %>%
    spread(group1, number) %>%
    left_join(mydf, .)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `rename`, `gather`, `unite` and `spread`.